# Resources on how build your own Mobile Phone?

Tags: mobile, webos

Now that webOS is opensource I am trying to find any resources on building your own mobile phone in the US. That is put webOs on some custom hardware that has 3G voice access.

I realize this question is not a programming question but I could not find another StackExchange that was applicable.

Comment: What specific resources are you looking for? Do you have hardware questions, programming questions?

Comment: Like has anyone done this before (I found some in Germany that did it) and has a blog post or how-to on it. I thought it would be a fun project to try but it might beyond my reach with out some starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at [OpenMoko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openmoko) and their history of attempting to release phones based on open hardware specifications for open source mobile operating systems.

Per the wiki article, Openmoko phones now support Android, Debian, Gentoo, Qt Extended Improved, QtMoko, and SHR.  The announcement of the webOS opensourcing means that it's possible that webOS could be ported, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely going to have to wait a bit before using just any hardware. While webOS is going open source, right now the only thing that's released is Enyo (the application framework, minus the UI elements). There are other components to the OS that are still unreleased, and the OS runs on a modified linux kernel. They do plan, however, to release a version by the end of this year, called open webOS 1.0, which will run on a standard linux kernel.